# Kinect v2 BodyFrameReader shall capture specific joints in C#

Tags: kinect-sdk

For my project i have to capture the legs of the body tracking, while a person is sitting. Especially the knees and feet. I’ve made it so far to draw my choosen joints in C#.

BUT if I put the Kinect under a table and the person is sitting in front of the table, the choosen joints start to flickering. I found out that the Kinect always tries to capture the whole body of the person. But the table prevents the Kinect of capturing the torso and the rest of the body. So my choosen joints for the legs can not be tracked correct.

My question is, how can I modify the BodyFrameReader to read or catupture only the legs, instead of the whole body? I am not talking about to draw my choosen joints. The BodyFrameReader of the BodyTracker shall only capture my joints. I use C#. 
Can someone help and give me a code example? Thanks a lot

Here my code snippet

```
kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();
bodyFrameReader = kinectSensor.BodyFrameSource.OpenReader();
kinectSensor.Open();
if (bodyFrameReader != null) {
bodyFrameReader.FrameArrived += Reader_FrameArrived;

private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e) {
        bool dataReceived = false;

        using (BodyFrame bodyFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame()) {
            if (bodyFrame != null) {
                if (bodies == null) {
                    bodies = new Body[bodyFrame.BodyCount]; 
                }
```